# In Python, how to re-arrange items in a list in an order specified in another list of lists?

Tags: python

The permutations are specified in the following list of lists:

```
 lines = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0],
    [4, 0, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7, 1, 5]]
```

This list is supposed to be re-arranged in the orders specified in 'lines':

```
data = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

Example permutation (following the sequence 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0),

random = [i,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a]

What I've tried:

```
for entries in lines:
    for shuffle in entries:
        random.append(data[shuffle])
```

Comment: Please don't post "what you tried" snippets as an answer.

Comment: Well, it is the answer though IMO!

Comment: If you have an answer then why ask a question?

Comment: @Leb the site had this checkbox which said "Answer your own question, share your knowledge" I thought I might do that. Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer I think there's nothing wrong in doing it Ketcomp, as long as it's a definitive answer and it works. If it's just some random code you've tried, then it belongs in the question.

Comment: It's not at all clear how the output is supposed to correspond to the input, and the answer you posted doesn't produce anything like the output you say you want.

Comment: According to @ThiefMaster the answer is a single statement `random = [data[shuffle] for entries in lines for shuffle in entries]` 
How could random be made a list of lists with each list in random containing one permutation?

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes? @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you can do it with [itemgetter from operator module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#operator.getitem) by making a function and then call it up to your needs, this way:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> def sorting(lists,i,data):
        return [x for x in itemgetter(*lists[i])(data)]

>>> random = sorting(lines,1,data)
['i', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'a']
```

Alternatively,

You can just use the built-in method [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#map) to get your `data` list sorted(proper term here) according to your `permutation` list of lists, this way:

```
>>> def sorting(lists,i,data):
        return map(data.__getitem__,lists[i])
>>> random = sorting(lines,1,data)
['i', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'a']
```

Comment: This works! However, I am using ThiefMaster's suggestion of using this:`random = [data[shuffle] for entries in lines for shuffle in entries]`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are working with permutations, I would recommend taking a look at numpy arrays. Specifically, this "rearrange via permutation" operation becomes straightforward indexing as `arr[perm]`.